# Changing Content of Tabs

Tags: android

I have an program with three tabs (three activities).  There is a CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE ListView in the first tab (you can only select one item).  I would like to know how to make the SECOND TAB activity dependent on the what is clicked in the first tab.

Here is the code in the first tab:

```
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, GENRES));
    final ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
}

private static final String[] GENRES = new String[] {
    "Action", "Adventure", "Animation", "Children", "Comedy", "Documentary", "Drama",
    "Foreign", "History", "Independent", "Romance", "Sci-Fi", "Television", "Thriller"};
```

THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Fire off an intent with the selection from the list being passed as an extra. To achieve this, you'll have to set up an onClickListener for your listview. When the onClickListener is fired, it will launch the second activity with the choice included as a parameter.

  ```
  listView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
  {
      public void onClick(View v)
      {
          //declare intent and startActivity(intent) here
      }
  });
  ```
- OR you can set a sharedpreference for the choice the user makes in the first tab. When the second tab is launched, it can reference the sharedpreference and work accordingly. 
  [Android.com Example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)